# The limit of $(x^3+\cos x+e^{-2x})/(x^2 \sqrt{x^2+1})$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

I have this infinity problem which I do not know the answer to:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3+\cos x+e^{-2x}}{x^2 \sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

I thaught that because $x^3$ is the fastest growing part, this would be infinity, but WolframAlpha says that this will be equal to $1.$

Comment: In the numerator the fastest growing part is $x^3$and in the denominator too (since $x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}$ goes like $x^3$).
For this reason the result is $1$.

Comment: In fact, in the denominator, you have $\sqrt{x^2+1}$, so you have $x^3$ in the numerator and $x^3$ in the denominator, so the result is $1$

Comment: One way is to divide top and bottom by $x^3$.

Comment: I do not get how I could have x³ in the denominator... How is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the whole thing by $x^3$ and you get $$\frac{1+\cos x/x^3+e^{-2x}/x^3}{\sqrt{1+1/x^2}}$$

now as $x\to\infty$, all the terms go to $0$, leaving the limit as $1$.

Comment: So you divided $x²\sqrt{x²+1}$ by x³ also?

Comment: Yes, I divided the numerator and denominator :)

Comment: $\frac{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^3}=\frac{x^2}{x^2}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}$

Comment: I get it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3+\cos x+e^{-2x}}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{\cos x}{x^3}+\frac{e^{-2x}}{x^3}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}=1$$